# Не удается установить Laravel/sail в существующий проект

Tags: laravel

Я установил Docker Desktop для работы с Laravel. Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь установить в уже существующий проект Sail  с помощью команды

```
composer require laravel/sail --dev
```

, которая в процессе установки выдает мне сообщение

```
Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.4|^8.0 but your PHP version (7.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - league/commonmark 2.0.2 requires php ^7.4 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.        
    - league/commonmark 2.0.2 requires php ^7.4 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.        
    - league/commonmark 2.0.2 requires php ^7.4 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.        
    - Installation request for league/commonmark (locked at 2.0.2) -> satisfiable by league/commonmark[2.0.2].
```

Ранее я использовал для в качестве среды окружения для работы с этим приложением Vagrant/Homestead, который у меня сломался и я перешел на Docker, но без установки Sail и устновки docker-compose.yml file я не смогу работать с этим приложением в новой среде. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможные способы решения проблемы.

Comment: Вам нужно поднять версию PHP, там же напсано.

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить игнорируя условия для расширений и версии PHP

```bsh
# Install sail
$ composer require laravel/sail --dev --ignore-platform-reqs
$ php artisan sail:install

# Start docker compose
$ vendor/bin/sail up -d

# Install packages for project php version
$ vendor/bin/sail composer update
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь и подсказки! Проблему решил, скачав более свежую версию php (7.4.27).